# Mongodb for each group find document with largest value of specific field (argmax)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

After performing unwind in my aggreagate pipeline I have intermediate result such as :

```
[
{_id:1, precision:0.91, recall:0.71, other fields...},
{_id:1, precision:0.71, recall:0.81, other fields...},
{_id:1, precision:0.61, recall:0.91, other fields...},
{_id:2, precision:0.82, recall:0.42, other fields...},
{_id:2, precision:0.72, recall:0.52, other fields...},
{_id:2, precision:0.62, recall:0.62, other fields...}
]
```

now I would like to group the documents by _id, then in each group find the document with maximum recall, and obtain recall, precison and _id for this document.

So the result would be :

```
[
    {_id:1, precisionOfDocWithMaxRecall:0.61, maxRecall:0.91},
    {_id:2, precisionOfDocWithMaxRecall:0.62, maxRecall:0.62}
]
```

I have managed to obtain the result using group and max but without the precision field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run the following pipeline, it uses the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator to order the documents getting into the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline first and then uses the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** (or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)**, depending on the sort direction) to return the first/last element in the ordered list:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /* previous pipeline */
    { "$sort": { "recall": -1 } },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "precisionOfDocWithMaxRecall": { "$first": "$precision" },
            "maxRecall": { "$first": "$recall" }
        }
    }
])
```